# How to get ASCII values of a string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, ascii

I want to be able so get the ASCII values of all the characters in a string.
I can get the ASCII value of a character but i cannot do it for the whole string.

My attempt:

```
dim input as string = console.readline()
dim value as integer = ASC(input)

'Then I am changing its value by +1 to write the input in a secret code form.
console.writeline(CHR(value+1))
```

I want to be able to get the ASCII values for all characters in the string so i can change the all letters in the string +1 character in the alphabet.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that the string is made up from *more* than one ASCII character code?  VB.NET will happily accept your borken code however, ASC only looks at the first character and ignores the rest.

Comment: Yes but I don't know the command to get the ASCII values for the whole string. I only know how to do so for a single character :/

Comment: Well, you could just copy/paste the title of your question into the Google query box and get the same answer you selected.  Did you try?

Comment: A .NET string is a counted sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a codepoint. Unicode is a superset of ASCII. When you say "ASCII codes" do you really mean Unicode codepoint? Regardless, in general, adding 1 to a character code can result in an invalid characters code; You need range checking and/or wrap-around logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim asciis As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
```

If you want to increase each letter's ascii value you can use this code:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To asciis.Length - 1
    asciis(i) = CByte(asciis(i) + 1)
Next
Dim result As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciis)
```

Comment: I am getting an error when compiling the program. " 'Encoding' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: @Phalanx: if you click on the error Visual Studio would have told you that it's in the `System.Text` namespace and suggest to add the import. However, you can also use the fully qualified class, edited my answer.

Comment: Oh right, I was using the CMD though so i could not see how to fix the error. However your fix works thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
      System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim a As Integer
        a = Asc(TextBox1.Text)
        MessageBox.Show(a)

    End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been almost three years now, but let me show you this.

**Function to convert String to Ascii (You already have a String in your Code). You can use either (Asc) or (Ascw)** ... for more information, please read [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions)

```
Dim Input As String = console.readline()
Dim Value As New List(Of Integer)
For Each N As Char In Input
Value.Add(Asc(N) & " ")
Next
Dim OutPutsAscii As String = String.Join(" ", Value)
```

**Function to Convert Ascii to String (What you asked for). You can use either (Chr) or (ChrW)** ... for more information, please read [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions)

```
Dim Value1 As New List(Of Integer)
Dim MyString As String = String.Empty
For Each Val1 As Integer In Value1
MyString &= ChrW(Val1)
Next
```