# Need help converting text into NATO phonetic alphabet

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to convert a text in a text box into the phonetic alphabet and I am not sure how. I have `TextBox1` as my main textbox, the button to convert is `Button9` and I would like the output to be in `Label10`.

An example of what I am trying to get is someone enters `Test` for example into the textbox, clicks the button, and the label shows `Tango Echo Sierra Tango`.

If possible it would be nice to have it automatically translate while you type it in.

I have tried using some sample code I found on the internet from [How to replace letters on a textbox using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736372/how-to-replace-letters-on-a-textbox-using-vb-net) but it is not doing it the way I would like when translating.

(Sample of what I tried without adding in the actual phonetic alphabet)

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("a") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", "c")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("b") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("b", "d")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("c") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("c", "e")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("d") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("d", "f")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("e") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("e", "g")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("f") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("f", "h")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("g") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("g", "i")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("h") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("h", "j")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("i") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("i", "k")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("j") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("j", "l")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("k") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("k", "m")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("l") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("l", "n")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("m") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("m", "o")

End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("n") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("n", "p")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("o") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("o", "q")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("p") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("p", "r")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("q") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("q", "s")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("r") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("r", "t")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("s") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("s", "u")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("t") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("t", "v")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("u") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("u", "w")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("v") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("v", "x")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("w") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("w", "y")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("x") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("x", "z")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("y") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("y", "a")
End If

If TextBox1.Text.Contains("z") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("z", "b")
End If
```

Each letter was translating, and it was not showing it in the right box. I am fairly new to VB and have not done this type of thing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Here is *one* of these.  It may not be the best but it does give you an idea of how you can achieve it.

Firstly, I've defined a dictionary (`Phonetic`) that maps a capitalised first letter to the phonetic equivalent:

```
Dim Phonetic As Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' List of phonetic words
    Dim Words() As String = {"Alfa", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X - ray", "Yankee", "Zulu"}

    ' Create dictionary to hold words and load with words
    Phonetic = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each Word As String In Words
        Phonetic.Add(Word.Substring(0, 1), Word)
    Next
End Sub
```

This dictionary is a member variable so it can be accessed anywhere on the form.  Make sure to define it (`Dim ...`) at the Form level and not inside a method or event handler.

Next, when the button is clicked, each letter of the textbox is evaluated, and the appropriate phonetic word returned from the dictionary.  A space is also added.  The result is trimmed (to remove the last space) and displayed in the label:

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    LoadOutput()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadOutput()
    If Not Phonetic Is Nothing Then
        Dim Output As String = String.Empty

        For Each Letter As String In TextBox1.Text.ToUpper()
            Output += Phonetic(Letter) + " "
        Next
        Output = Output.Trim()

        Label10.Text = Output
    End If
End Sub
```

When clicking the button, this will output what you are looking for.  There are many other ways of accomplishing this task - this is just an example of one way you could do it.

To automatically translate the text when you type into the `TextBox`, just use the `TextChanged` event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    LoadOutput()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Following comment from OP to also handle invalid characters (including spaces).

This is achieved in `LoadOutput` by checking for the presence of the letter in the `Dictionary`.  If the letter does not exist, we append it without converting.  If it does, we just convert it as before and append it:

```
Private Sub LoadOutput()
        ...
        For Each Letter As String In TextBox1.Text.ToUpper()
            If Phonetic.ContainsKey(Letter) Then
                Output += Phonetic(Letter) + " "
            Else
                Output += Letter
            End If
        Next
        ...
End Sub
```

Regarding the request to convert `1` to `One` and so forth, that requires some additional effort.  You would have to manually add these to the dictionary during `Form1_Load`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(...)
    ...
        Phonetic.Add(Word.Substring(0, 1), Word)
    Next
    Phonetic.Add("1", "One")
    Phonetic.Add("2", "Two")
    ... (And so on)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well, however it does not like numbers or spaces, is there any way to make them an exception? Or turn "1" into "One" for example?

Comment: @ICreativeCrum I've edited the answer to include a way to handle the additional requests

Comment: Hi, sorry for all the questions, I seem to be getting some errors, one says Next' must be preceded by a matching 'For and the other say 'Word' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @ICreativeCrum I suspect you have made a minor copy and paste error. I have this code running and working. I can edit the question again and past each of the functions in so you have the whole thing, if that'd help?

Comment: @ICreativeCrum Also please don't copy the three dots `...`. They are just there to indicate that there is content before and after the code

Comment: Hello, I am not sure how to paste code, so this is what I currently have - https://pastebin.com/2NWZYe8U. Ignore the line spaces, its just me showing each block of code

Comment: You have double-added this code: `Phonetic.Add(Word.Substring(0, 1), Word)` and `Next`.  You need to remove line 11 and 12.